# How can I add a value to every object of a list at the first position in R

Tags: r, list, position, element, addition

I wonder if there is a way to add a "0" to every element of a R-list at the first position.

```
mylist <- list (a = 1:5, b = 11:15)
```

I'm looking for an easy way that produces the following result:

```
mylist[[1]]
```

> [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5

```
mylist[[2]]
```

> [1] 0 11 12 13 14 15

Of course my list has much more objects than just two.

Comment: Try the `lapply` function. `lapply(mylist, function(x) "put your function here")` Imagine writing a command to do this for a vector, say `x`. Put that command inside the "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lapply` takes a list as an argument, applies a function to each element and returns a list of the results

```
lapply( mylist , function(x) c(0,x))

$a
[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5

$b
[1]  0 11 12 13 14 15
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Map` like below

```
mylist[] <- Map(c, 0, mylist)
```

such that

```
> mylist
$a
[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5

$b
[1]  0 11 12 13 14 15
```